# Effect where numbers count as the element appears

Tags: javascript, css

I want to implement the effect where the numbers count up to a number on my website, but I can't figure out how to go about doing it. An example of what I want to achieve can be found here: http://www.winshipwealth.com/#winship-numbers (it takes a few seconds for the website to load and scroll to the part I am talking about)

Comment: http://bfintal.github.io/Counter-Up/demo/demo.html